# Java socket remote desktop connection

Tags: java, sockets

Hi so am trying to connect to a remote desktop but i can't seem to get any packet is there a way to get any packet and print it no matter what characters and numbers it contains or no matter what size it is,

Any help is wonderful thank you.

This is the code i tested it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InetSocketAddress rdpSocket = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 3389);
    Socket rdp_Con = new Socket();
    try {
        rdp_Con.connect(rdpSocket);
        if (rdp_Con.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected To Remote Desktop Checking Packets...");
            int red;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            byte[] redData;
            while ((red = rdp_Con.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > -1) {
                redData = new byte[red];
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, redData, 0, red);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(redData));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You better not publish your ``SERVER4`` in ```PSLEUROPE``` domain IP on public forum:) According your question: I am not RDP protocol guru, but looks like you should send something to server before reading response. BTW: binary proprietary closed protocol (RDP) is not the best protocol to start studying network programming. Start with HTTP.

Comment: Does it output *"Connected To Remote Desktop Checking Packets..."*? There might be several issues, starting from the server being behind a NAT to the RDP's handshake method.

Comment: Yes it does out put that.

Comment: You may use `Wireshark` to capture the packets in a real scenario, to know the request-response pattern and try to simulate it. You would be successful in case if the packets are not encrypted! All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. The RDP protocol is encrypted and starts with a client authentication. The RDP server will never send you anything until you successfully negotiate a handshake, and when it does it will be encrypted.

Try another protocol.

Answer (score 0):

you should understatand Rdp Connection Sequence as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/023f1e69-cfe8-4ee6-9ee0-7e759fb4e4ee)
start X.224 Connection Request PDU [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/49095420-c6ef-4256-a262-3800e1e233a7)

```
        InetSocketAddress rdpSocket = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.52.159", 3389);
    Socket rdp_Con = new Socket();
    try {
        rdp_Con.connect(rdpSocket);
        DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(rdp_Con.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(rdp_Con.getOutputStream()));
        if (rdp_Con.isConnected()) {
           
            System.out.println("Connected To Remote Desktop Checking Packets...");
            //X.224 Connection Request PDU encoded in HEX (hexdump)
            String X224rq ="0300002a25e00000000000436f6f6b69653a206d737473686173683d726f6f740d0a010008000b000000";
            // Convert Hex sequence to byte 
            byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(X224rq ,16).toByteArray();
            //send to RDP server 
            out.write(bytes);
            out.flush();
            //Define packet to be recieved from rdp server
            byte [] packet = new byte[20];
            //read Packets
            ins.readFully(packet,0,10);
            //display Server X.224 Connection Confirm PDU
            System.out.println("recv: " + Hex.toHexString(packet)); 
            // TODO ;continue sequence as described in rdp protocol
            
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rdp_Con.close();
```